# ASP.NET Identity Update multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have two databases where one handles user authentication (asp.net default identity tables) and the other handles other data, which also has a custom user table.

I am attempting to update user information in the aspnetuser table which will also update the custom user table in the other database. The code I have does not update the necessary fields in aspnetuser table and creates a new record in the custom user table, which is not the desired result. The below is the code I have so far.

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, ApplicationUser appUser)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        //locate appUser Id from AspNetUser table
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(appUser.Id);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        //locate email address that exists in the custom User table
        var contextUser = _context.UserTable.Where(u => u.Email == appUser.Email);

        if (contextUser == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(appUser);

                UserTable personInfo = new User();
                personInfo.FirstName = appUser.FirstName;
                personInfo.LastName = appUser.LastName;
                personInfo.EmailAddress = appUser.Email;

                _context.UserTable.Update(personInfo);
                await aspnetdBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {

            }
        }
        return Ok(appUser);
```

When I am testing through postman, I am getting an Ok 200 code with the changed json result. The aspnetuser table still does not update the required field. Nor does it locate the user in the custom user table. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hmm.. I haven't worked in core much, but asp.net identity isn't really relevant to your function scope here.  it's more of an entity framework question it seems.  It comes down to your understanding of context and entities which are essentially context bound models.  In this case, your aren't modifying entities (that requires you query the entity, change the entity properties, update by passing it back in, then save) and I don't see you handling any entity for `aspnetdBContext` here at all.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use the user retrieved from the database to prevent creation of new user in your table, no need to create a user using `new`

```
//UserTable personInfo = new User();
contextUser.FirstName = appUser.FirstName;
contextUser.LastName = appUser.LastName;
contextUser.EmailAddress = appUser.Email;
```

this will help you update your custom user table.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe the UserTable and AppUser table are related as one to relationship or may be one to many in that case if User table and appuser table are related then you can simplify your code as

```
   try
            {
                appUser.personInfo.FirstName = appUser.FirstName;
                appUser.personInfo.LastName = appUser.LastName;
                appUser.personInfo.EmailAddress = appUser.Email;
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(appUser); 
                await aspnetdBContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {

            }
```

you might wanna look into ef Lazyloading and eagerLoading  concepts for a better understanding of how these works